# Filter by a field that's a foreign key

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Using Yii2.

I have a table called 'calificacion' that has a foreign key 'alumno-id' that points to field id in table alumno.

The column defined in the GridView widget is:

```
        [
            'header' => 'Alumno',
            'attribute' => 'alumno.id',
            'value' => 'alumno.name'
        ],
```

And it's showing perfectly, but the filter, in the header of the column, is not appearing. I want to have a textbox for writing the name of the alumno and get filtered. How can I achieve that?

**EDIT**: Here're the files https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7059378/Desktop.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First declare an attribute in your `SearchModel`.

```
public $alumno_name;
```

In your search model's rule add:

```
[['alumno_name'], 'safe'],
```

Join with `alumno` relation in search method (supponsinbly there is a `alumno` relation in your `Calificacion` model):

```
$query = Calificacion::find()
    ->joinWith(['alumno alumno']);
```

To sort with `$alumno_name` add:

```
$dataProvider->sort = [
    'attributes' => [

        //Other attributes here

        'alumno_name' => [
            'asc' => ['alumno.name' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['alumno.name' => SORT_DESC],
        ],
    ]
];
```

To filter this you have to add:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'alumno.name', $this->alumno_name]);
```

Finally in your grid view add:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'alumno_name',
    'value' => 'alumno.name'
],
```

You can find more info [**here**](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/) and [**here**](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/).

Also instead of `header` use `'label' => 'Alumno'`.

Comment: You don't need to add a fake attribute : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#working-with-model-relations

Comment: Oh, nice. I hadn't noticed that. Thanks!

Comment: Did that, and can see the field on the index table, but can't search! I edited the post with the files.

Comment: You don't need the `public $alumno_id`. It's already defined in `Calification` class. Also, you are trying to search by `alumno_id` that in validation rules is validating as integer.

Comment: Try again the approach I have in my answer. It should work. Just add `public $alumno_name` , add the virtual attribute as safe in rules (not integer),  change sort attribute `alumno_id` to `alumno_name`, and filter using `$this->alumno_name` instead of `$this->alumno_id`. Finally, in grid view replace `alumno_id` with `alumno_name`.

Answer (score 0):

You must first define a relation in Model of that table 'calificacion', like

```
public function getAlumno()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Alumno::className(), ['id' => 'alumno_id']);
}
```

Than in the search model of Calificacion set that you are joining tables after validation, like

`$query->joinWith('alumno')`;

Than set search like

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'alumno.id' => $this.alumno_id
]);
```

Comment: Did that, and can see the field on the index table, but can't search! I edited the post with the files.